# How can I get the current URL of the page [php]

Tags: php, url

I have a site which can access by users(www.mysite.com/user/home.php) and an admin(www.mysite.com/admin/administrator/index.php).

I have a line of code that automatically logs out a user (like expiring the session) if condition meet.
Unfortunately admin will also logged out. how I can get the website url using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URl']
```

so that my line of code will only run for the users pages and not for admin pages "/admin/administrator". Something like..

```
   if(the website url != "www.mysite.com/admin/administrator/"){ //run the code here}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a session variable identifying if the user is an admin or not?

Comment: Agreed.  You should use a session to identify a logged in user as an admin after they have successfully authenticated themselves.  Your admin portion of the site only needs to check if the user is an admin, otherwise redirect them.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. I just add a admin session variable of admins when they logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strpos` function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside other:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URl'], 'admin/administrator') !== false) {
    echo 'admin dir';
}
```

Note that the use of `!== false` is deliberate; strpos returns either the offset at which the needle string begins in the haystack string, or the boolean false if the needle isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I just add an admin session variable to all the admins who logged in to admin page. By this I can know if the admin is logged in to the page or not.

```
if($_SESSION['is_admin'] != 1){//the code here}
```

Thank you for the help guys!